# Pick single random value from WhiteNoiseProcess

Tags: functions, random

I have the following:

```
m = 6.137*10^-13; k = 1.5*m; 
stddev = Sqrt[2*k]*Sqrt[m];
whiteNoise = WhiteNoiseProcess[stddev]
```

**How can I produce a function that gives me for each call a single random value from `WhiteNoiseProcess`?**

I tried the following which seems to me not very clever:

```
getValue[time_] := Module[
   {t = time},
   data = RandomFunction[whiteNoise, {t, t + 1}];
   data[[2, 1, 1, 1]]
];

getValue[1]

1.64153*10^-12
```

*I need for the upper case something similar like this:*

For a `NormalDistribution`:

I could simply write: `getValue[time_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]`

This returns also a value for real numbers which does not work with my example.

```
getValue[0.1]

-0.545294

getValue[1]

0.327526
```

Comment: You could do `RandomFunction[whiteNoise, {t, t + 1}]["FirstValue"]`.

Comment: @J. M. Thanks. So there is no other solution than picking the first one from 2 (or more) values?

Comment: I don't really know; that's why I didn't give an answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[getV];
getV[t_Integer]:= RandomVariate[whiteNoise[t]]
```

With a common random seed `getV` produces the same output as OP's `getValue`:

```
SeedRandom[1] 
res1 = getValue /@ Range[10];
SeedRandom[1] 
res2 = getV /@ Range[10]; 
res1 == res2
```

> True

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: @Lenoil, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.